# Teams import Excel date field incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, teams

I have excel file with columns formatted to dates as below:
[image]

When I tried to import data to Team as list I get below issue:

[image]

Can someone explain how to fix this ?

EDIT:

I did import the excell file to Team during List creation :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit 2

Oh ok i see it now , during import you have to convert data :), thanks!!

[image]

Comment: No, that value is correct (technically). It’s the number of days since December 30, 1899. // You do not mention how you “import” the data (copy/paste?) or where in Teams in even ends up. In a chat or channel? Or maybe some widget or embedded app?

Comment: Hi Daniel , Edited my post with method to import data

Comment: What kind of file format are you trying to import? Follow the steps to create the list first: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa

Comment: ok i see it now, you have to convert during import :) thank you

Comment: Please do not [edit] the answer into the question. You should write a separate answer.